# Cypress Migration Assistent appears on all branches, instead of the test-runner

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I have migrated one of my branches to Cypress 10.6
There are other branches, which shall further run on a lower Cypress version.
When I now run `npx cypress open` on one of my un-migrated branches, then the Migration Assistent appears. Instead of the old Cypress test-runner.

**How can I get rid of the Migration-Assistent and back to the normal test-runner?**

I don't want to migrate those branches, yet.